# double? to decimal? conversion

Tags: c#, nullable

Why after this code fragment:

```
 double? d = 123.4;
 decimal? dec = (decimal?)d; //dec is null
```

is dec's value null?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. Dec is 123.4 for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested on .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0, and I get `dec` as `123.4`, as expected. Are you sure you don't perhaps have the break-point too high?

Comment: Thanks. I test it again and it seems as some strange behaviour of Visual Studio/debugger. If I hover to dec variable after executing second line it says that dec is null but actual dec's value is 123.4 as expected (for example if I write it to console). That makes me first believe that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

dec isn't null, its 123.4

Answer (score 1):

I know this will point same thing. Your code gives me 123,4 as expected. It works fine.

I can just say try this :) but the result is same : 123,4

```
double? d = 123.4;
 decimal? dec = (decimal?)d.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the implicit conversion being called in the cast fails, leaving dec with a null value, rather than whatever truncated/rounded value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not null. You must have an error elsewhere.